# Should I use AsyncTask or IntentService to update Dates by URL Once in a day?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

In my app I use `AsyncTask` to get datas from an URL. By this URL, I update my app everyday with some new data.
However, I'm wondering which is the best for me `AsyncTask` or `IntentService` to update my datas by URL and download it once in a day?

Comment: create service implementing AlarmManager which runs ones in a day

Comment: @  Murtaza Hussain .you have any demo code...???

Comment: I am posting that as an answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have intentService UP and Running

call your intentService for once a day

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyServiceReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,  0, myIntent, 0);

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60); // first time
  long frequency= 86400000 * 1000; // every 24 hours
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), frequency, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this site for a comparison between Services, Threads, IntentServices and  [AsyncTasks](http://www.onsandroid.com/2011/12/difference-between-android.html).

But personally I think you should use an [AlarmManager](http://vikinghammer.com/2012/04/22/android-use-alarmmanager-instead-of-a-service-with-a-timertask/).